# Power method without unique largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Consider this question

[image]

I was able to do the first part of (a) with

[image]

and all of (b) in which I showed that the three vectors are dependent through which I was able to get, through some manipulation two eigenvalues and the  corresponding eigenvectors.

I am struggling to answer the second case of (a). That is

> Describe the asymptotic properties of the sequence $\mathbf{x}^{(k)}$,  $\lambda_i|<| \lambda_{n-1}|=| \lambda_n \mid, i=1, \ldots, n-2$. In the latter case explain how the (possibly complexalued) eigenvalues $\lambda_{n-1}, \lambda_n$ and their corresponding eigenvectors can be determined.

This case has never been covered by the course so I assume it should be a simple tweak of the argument in the afore mentioned theorem. Therefore, I wouldn't  find it too suprising if the result was
$$
\operatorname{dist}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}, \operatorname{span}\left(\boldsymbol{w}_1,\boldsymbol{w}_2\right)\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\rho^k\right).
$$

If this is true, then I do not know how to answer the other part of (a). In particular, the above will tell me that we go to a vector in the plane spanned by the two vectors, but I don't see how this helps me in finding them.

**Question:** What happens in the case
$$
\left|\lambda_i\right|<\left|\lambda_{n-1}\right|=\left|\lambda_n\right|, i=1, \ldots, n-2
$$
and how can the eigenvalues/eigenvectors be determined (in that case)?

Comment: A generalization of the manipulation that you did in part (b) is exactly what they're looking for when they ask how to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors in part (a)

Comment: You're right about the convergence rate, with $\rho = |\lambda_{n-2}|/|\lambda_n|$

Comment: Hi @BenGrossmann, thank you for this. Do you think that it is sufficient to say that? I tried to be explicit but I do not believe this will always work. Also feel free to post the above as answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Based on the wording of the question, it looks like that would be sufficient and a formal proof is not required. Regarding finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I put an explicit procedure into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess that
$$
\operatorname{dist}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}, \operatorname{span}\left(\boldsymbol{w}_1,\boldsymbol{w}_2\right)\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\rho^k\right)
$$
is correct, with $\rho = |\lambda_{n-2}|/|\lambda_n|$. Here, $\boldsymbol w_1, \boldsymbol w_2$ are eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_{n-1}$ and $\lambda_n$ respectively. As you say, it should be possible for you to tweak whatever proof you were presented in order to show that this is the case.

Regarding the computation of the eigenvectors: denote $U = \operatorname{span}\left(\boldsymbol{w}_1,\boldsymbol{w}_2\right)$. Notably, $U$ is an invariant subspace of $A$. For sufficiently large $k$, you can guarantee that $\mathbf y_k \in U$ (up to numerical precision). Thus, the vectors $\mathbf y_k,\mathbf y_{k+1}, \mathbf y_{k+2}$ are all elements of the invariant subspace $U$. Also, assuming that we weren't astronomically lucky and happened to converge to $\text{span}(\boldsymbol w_i)$ for $i = 1$ or $i = 2$, we know that the vectors $\mathbf y_k, \mathbf y_{k+1}$ are linearly independent. Thus, $\mathbf y_k, \mathbf y_{k+1}$ form a basis of the 2-dimensional $U$.

Now, the eigenvalues/eigenvectors we're after are the eigenvalues of the restriction $A|_U$. We may compute the matrix of the restriction $A|_U$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{\mathbf y_k, \mathbf y_{k+1}\}$. If $\mathbf y_{k+2} = a\mathbf y_{k} + b\mathbf y_{k+1}$, then the fact that $A \mathbf y_k = \mathbf y_{k+1}$ gives us
$$
[A|_U]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{0 & a\\1 & b} =: M.
$$
All this leads to the following procedure by which we can obtain the eigenvalues/eigenvectors that we're after.

1. Obtain vectors $\mathbf y_k, \mathbf y_{k+1}, \mathbf y_{k+2}$ for a sufficiently large $k$
2. Solve the linear system $a\mathbf y_k + b \mathbf y_{k+1} = \mathbf y_{k+2}$.
3. Obtain eigenvalues $\mu_1,\mu_2$ of the matrix $M$ described above and corresponding eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1 = (v_{11}, v_{12})$ and $\mathbf v_2 = (v_{21}, v_{22})$.
4. The eigenvalues we're after are $\lambda_{n-1} = \mu_1$ and $\lambda_{n} = \mu_2$. The corresponding eigenvectors are
   $$
   \boldsymbol w_1 = v_{11}\mathbf y_1 + v_{12} \mathbf y_2, \qquad 
   \boldsymbol w_2 = v_{21}\mathbf y_1 + v_{22} \mathbf y_2.
   $$